# TYPO3 Indexed Search remove operator feature

Tags: typo3, typoscript

TYPO3's Indexed Search uses operators (+, -, | -> AND, NOT, OR) as a feature for advanced searching. unfortunately there is no known way to disable this feature. Do have a clue to remove those operator statements in TYPO3?

As an example, if you try to search for "Kim Jong-un", the search result will display the following line: "Search for "Kim" and "Jong" but not "un".
So if you have named an article or a page in typo3 "Kim Jong-un", you shall not find it through the search.

TYPO3 4.7.5

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to TYPO3 6.x. This is fixed and you can disable those operators.

I had same needs with TYPO3 4.6.